# WCF service does not allow http HEAD method when getting wsdl?

Tags: c#, .net, http, wcf, wsdl

I have a self hosted (using Topshelf) WCF service, which uses basicHttpBinding - so it communicates using http POST methods.
If I go to url http://localhost:54020/MyService?wsdl - then it performs GET to fetch wsdl of the service. The actual action performed:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -URI 'http://localhost:54020/MyService?wsdl' -Method GET
```

Then if I try to use HEAD method, it gives me an error: 400 Bad Request.
Though I know that WCF does not support other methods by default, and if you want to use them you have to define it with [WebInvoke(Method="httpMethod")] attribute, but this weird that it does not allow yo use HEAD when only asking for WSDL.

Does anyone know why it is not allowed to use HEAD method when asking for WCF service WSDL?